# dojo - how to allow a module to popup a dialog

Tags: dojo

i have a module. I need it to be able to display a modal dialog.

Seems like I need to inject a div into the main DOM and then parse it. Is this the right approach. Are there samples (or even a util- seems like this would not be that uncommon)

Answer (score 5):

There are samples for almost everything in [DojoCampus](http://docs.dojocampus.org/dijit/Dialog) and in the [tests directory](http://download.dojotoolkit.org/release-1.3.1/dojo-release-1.3.1/dijit/tests/test_Dialog.html):

```
var pane = dojo.byId('thirdDialog');    
thirdDlg = new dijit.Dialog({
  id: "dialog3",
  refocus:false,
  title: "Programatic Dialog Creation"
},pane);
```

Note that this particular widget doesn't need to be inserted to the DOM manually - it appends itself to the end of the page. Here the second parameter to the Dialog constructor - pane - is a reference to the node whose content should be displayed inside the Dialog.

**UPDATE:** Based on the new information you should try this:

```
dojo.require("dijit.Dialog");
dojo.addOnLoad(function() {
    secondDlg = new dijit.Dialog({
        title: "Programatic Dialog Creation",
        style: "width: 300px",
        content: "Insert text here"
    });
    secondDlg.show()
});
```

As shown here, you can pass Dialog content in the `content` attribute. *(This sample is executable in FireBug on any page that includes Dojo.)*

**UPDATE:** So, you want to have a form inside the Dialog? Nothing special here. Hey, you can even have a dijit form over there! Be sure to check out that [DojoCampus article on Dialogs](http://docs.dojocampus.org/dijit/Dialog) to learn how Dialog can communicate with a dijit form.

```
dojo.require("dijit.Dialog");
dojo.require("dijit.form.TextBox");
dojo.addOnLoad(function() {
    secondDlg = new dijit.Dialog({
        title: "Programatic Dialog Creation",
        style: "width: 300px",
        content: "<h2>Sample Form</h2>" +
            "name: <input dojoType='dijit.form.TextBox' type='text' name='name' id='name'>"
    });
    secondDlg.show()
});
```

*(Again this sample is executable in FireBug on any page that includes Dojo.)*

Comment: i dont understand, where is thirdDialog?

Comment: 'thirdDialog' is the id of a div element on that test page. Simply view the page source, search for 'thirdDialog' and you'll find an element that is initially hidden.